# Which part of my website does the use of a CC -by-sa licensed picture affect?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

If I use a CC -by -sa licensed picture (modified by cropping and text overlay) on my website, what part of my website does the "contagious" nature of the license affect?

- Do I need to license the modified picture under CC -by-sa? (probably yes)
- Do I need to license the page/post text used with the picture under CC -by-sa? (maybe?)
- Do I need to place all the content on my website under CC -by-sa? (I guess not)
- Do I need to license the work I do for clients via my website under CC -by-sa (almost certainly not)

The question comes down to what the definition of a derivative work is. Any ideas?

Comment: I think many of your questions might depend on how essential the picture is to the website and to a lesser extent on what the rest of the content on the site is. If this picture has significant monetary value to you or the creator, you should consult a lawyer. A better option might be to contact the creator to discuss an alternative license.

Comment: I'd say: yes (that's ShareAlike), no, no, no. (IANAL.)